Convert URLs in string to hyperlinks, but only display domain + .com
I have the following PHP code to convert URLs in a string to hyperlinks, however, Id really like to have the resulting display hyperlink only show the domain and .com. So the resulting output would look like this:
<a href="https://www.britannica.com/topic/Apollo-11" target="_blank">www.britannica.com</a>

or
<a href="https://www.britannica.com/topic/Apollo-11" target="_blank">britannica.com</a>

Here is what I currently have:
$text_with_links = preg_replace ( 
    "/(?<!a href=\")(?<!src=\")((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i",
    "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"blank\">\\0</a>", $text
);

Any tips would be appreciated

Please provide sufficient sample input with the expected output.

You would need to capture the domain and insert at the desired position, something like this demo (also I modified your regex a bit - only would use if it's my own html and not arbitrary)

@bobble bubble - awesome! That works perfectly and it's simple. I appreciate it. How to I accept this as the answer?

@Chris Happy that helped. They do not like answers where html gets parsed with use of regex here on Stack Overflow. You can find here how (*SKIP)(*F) works and here how capturing and replace works. Either put an answer yourself (you are welcome to use my demo) but be prepared for getting downvoted - or just leave the question as it is, for someone else to answer. Or you have a better idea!

Understood. Thank you!
